# JDBC connection from eclipse not working, but working in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, eclipse, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect into DB via JDBC

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port:service_name"; //Changed the host_name, port and service_name for confidentiality
String username = "user_name"; // Changed the user_name
String password = "my_password"; //Changed the password  
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Got the below exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
```

But at the same time, I could connect via Oracle SQL developer.

Note- My service_name consists of "." and "_" and My host_name contains "."

Please help here!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Step: 1
Load Driver Class
ex- Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

//Step: 2
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:portNo of oracle :database name";
ex- String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";

//Step: 3
User Name
String username = "user_name";
ex- String username = "system";

//Step: 3
Password
String password = "oracle_db_Password";
ex- String password = "sys123";

//Step:4 
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the right way to create data source object from oracle documentation:

//specify the datasource object

```
    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl");
    ods.setUser("scott");
    ods.setPassword("tiger");
    Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

I hope you are using it right way

Comment: what is the "info" object here?

Comment: This answer would be better if it had a link to that documentation.